# Recuperar WSDL de WebService NFe ASMX

Tags: java, web-service, nfe, wsdl

Como recupero o WSDL deste serviço: https://nfe.fazenda.sp.gov.br/ws/recepcaoevento.asmx

Preciso do WSDL para adicioná-lo pelo Netbeans, lá só consigo adicionar o WSDL e este é final asmx.

**EDIT**:

Minha CLasse está assim:

```
String nfeCabecMsg = "<nfeCabecMsg xmlns=\"http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2\">\n"
            + "\n"
            + "<cUF>35</cUF>\n"
            + "\n"
            + "<versaoDados>2.01</versaoDados>\n"
            + "\n"
            + "</nfeCabecMsg>";

String nfeDadosMsg = "<nfeDadosMsg xmlns=\"http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2\" versao=\"2.00\">\n"
            + "\n"
            + "<consStatServ xmlns=\"http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe\" versao=\"2.00\">\n"
            + "\n"
            + "<tpAmb>1</tpAmb>\n"
            + "\n"
            + "<cUF>35</cUF>\n"
            + "\n"
            + "<xServ>STATUS</xServ>\n"
            + "\n"
            + "</consStatServ>\n"
            + "\n"
            + "</nfeDadosMsg>";

String teste = new CadConsultaCadastro().getCadConsultaCadastroSoap().consultaCadastro(nfeCabecMsg, nfeDadosMsg);
```

Erro:

```
error: package br.inf.portalfiscal.nfe.wsdl.cadconsultacadastro does not exist
import br.inf.portalfiscal.nfe.wsdl.cadconsultacadastro.CadConsultaCadastro;
```

Porque está dando esse erro?

Answer (score 2):

Por padrão serviços publicado com ASMX deixam o WSDL acessívei em uma URL terminada com `?wsdl`, então você pode acessar o WSDL adicionando `?wsdl` desta url, algo assim:

https://nfe.fazenda.sp.gov.br/ws/recepcaoevento.asmx?wsdl

Isto significa que você está solicitando que o servidor gere e retorne o WSDL para você, caso isto não tenha sido desabilitado no servidor.

Alguns servidores também publicam o WSDL diretamente, mas é totalmente dependente da implementação/configuração, você pode tentar também algo como https://nfe.fazenda.sp.gov.br/ws/recepcaoevento.wsdl.

Outra coisa: este parece ser o serviço de recepção de eventos do estado de São Paulo. Você pode fazer download de todos os WSDL diretamente do site, [aqui](https://www.fazenda.sp.gov.br/nfe/url_webservices/url_webservices.asp). Adicionalmente, o contrato dos serviços é o mesmo para todas as UFs, alterando, para algumas, apenas o endereço do serviço. Se não conseguir acessar diretamente nem fazer o download, você pode tentar em algum outro: [relação dos werbservices](http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/webservices.aspx)

P.S.: não tenho certificado digital para validar o acesso aqui, veja se consegue e me confirme :)

Comment: olá, adicionando o wsdl não funciona, consegui baixar o arquivo e adicionar no projeto, comecei a fazer um teste, porem quando executo está falando que não existe.... ai dá o seguinte erro: package br.inf.portalfiscal.nfe.wsdl.cadconsultacadastro does not exist,;

Comment: @HimorriveL isso já é outra coisa, não tem relação nenhuma em como recuperar o WSDL. Faça outra pergunta, você editando a atual fica totalmente sem sentido. Basicamente a IDE gerou código para você e que, ou está em pacote diferente do que você está usando, ou não está no classpath.